# Pure ActionScript 3.0 - Memory Game

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3

I'm a beginner of ActionScript 3.0. I'm making a simple memory game, the tool I'm using is Eclipse with flexsdk plugin. Right now I've done the shuffle and display images, and the cover of the images as well.

My idea is when clicking on the image, the cover will remove and show the image behind of it. After 2 covers are gone, the game will compare and check whether the selected images are match or not, if match both of the images will remain, otherwise the cover will reappear and the game keeps going on. If all of the images are match, a winning line will appear.

The problem I'm facing is I got no idea on how to deal with the images comparison part. I wanted to compare with the index number of array or the name of the images, but I really don't have any idea. I've refer some examples but all of them are develop in CS3 and uses the timeframe which is not exist in pure ActionScript.

```
package  {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import myclasses.Cover;

 public class Prototype extends Sprite {
  protected static const WIDTH:int=3;
  protected static const HEIGHT:int=2;
  protected static const SPACINGX:int=100;
  protected static const SPACINGY:int=74;
  protected static const OFFSETX:int=96;
  protected static const OFFSETY:int=100;
  protected static const SIZE:Number=100;
  protected static const COLOUR:uint=0x999999;

  [Embed(source="images/pic1.jpg")]
  protected static const PIC1:Class;

  [Embed(source="images/pic2.jpg")]
  protected static const PIC2:Class;

  [Embed(source="images/pic3.jpg")]
  protected static const PIC3:Class;

  protected var imagesList:Array=[PIC1,PIC1,PIC2,PIC2,PIC3,PIC3];
  protected var X:int;
  protected var Y:int=27;
  protected var count:int;
  //protected var firstTap:Class;
  //protected var secondTap:Class;

  public function Prototype() {
   var shuffled:Array = shuffleList(imagesList.length);
   for(var i:int; i<imagesList.length; i++) {
    //var colour:uint;
    //colour=0x999999;
    var j:int = shuffled[i];
    var thing:Sprite=new Sprite();
      thing.addChild(new imagesList[j]());
      thing.x=X;
      thing.y=Y;
      addChild(thing);
      new Cover(this,X,Y,SIZE,COLOUR);
      X=X+SPACINGX+OFFSETX;
      count++;
      if(count == WIDTH){
       Y=Y+SPACINGY+OFFSETY;
       X=0;
      }
      addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,selectImages);
   }
  }
  public function selectImages(event:MouseEvent):void {
            //(P/S: this is not the actual code)
   var target:Sprite = Sprite(event.target)    
   if(firstTap == null){
    firstTap = ;    //1st selected image
    removeChild(target);
   }else if(secondTap == null){
    secondTap = ;   //2nd selected image
    if(firstTap == secondTap){
     firstTap = null;
     secondTap = null;
    }else{
     //firstTap = ; //cover back
     //secondTap = ; //cover back
     secondTap = null;
     firstTap = ;    //selected another image
    }
   }
  }

  protected function shuffleList(n:Number):Array {
      var startList:Array = new Array(n);
      var endList:Array = new Array(n);
      var i:Number, j:Number;

      for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
       startList[i] = i;
      }

      for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
       j = Math.floor(Math.random()*startList.length);
       endList[i] = startList.splice(j,1)[0];
      }
      return(endList);
  }
 }

}
```

Please help me figure out. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Chris for helping me fix the formatting =)

Answer (score 1):

Well I didn't really go through your code in details, but from looking at it, it seems you are making things really complex. So let me give you a hint in how I would do it...

1) First I would make a 'card' class, which extends sprite or bitmap, mainly containing the  image of that card, image of the cover/mask, some animtion methods like hide/show e.t.c, and possibly an 'id' variable to recognize it later, though that is not needed. You can also get away with the array you have, and in that case, skip step 2.

2) Now push two copies of each card in an array. 
example `[new card('c1'),new card('c1'),new card('c2'),new card('c2'),.....]`.

3) Now comes the part where you made it most complex, that is, the shuffling of the array. Let's write a custom function for it, shall we?

```
function shuffleArr(arr):Array
{
   var len:int = arr.length();
   for(var i:int=0; i<len; i++)
   {
      //Swap the value at i with a random value within the array;
      var tmp_pos:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
      while(tmp_pos==i)
      {
         tmp_pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
      }
      var tmp_var:card = arr[tmp_pos];
      arr[tmp_pos] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = tmp_var; 
   }
}
```

4) Now that the array is shuffled, you simply have to lay them out in a grid.

```
for(var row:int=0; row<6; row++)
{
  for(var col:int=0; col<6; col++)
  {
    card_arr[i].x = card_arr[i].width*cols+5;
    card_arr[i].y = card_arr[i].height*row+5;
    stage.addChild(card[i]);
  }
}
```

5) Now you have to check for user click and take action, and there are many ways to do it, but I will tell one of them... 
  a) Give the cards a click event handler, this becomes easy if the cards are a class, or you can look into `event.target` property and use a general click handler. it's up to you.
  b) On click, push the card's id in an array. If you did make them into a class, their ids should now be, c1, c2, e.t.c, and you can do

```
holder_arr.push(this);
this.removeCover();
```

6) Now you have to make sure, that the holder array can only hold two values at a time. Then do the checking. I am writing a semi-pseudo code with a lot of assumed functions and values:

```
//Insert
if(holder_arr.length()==2)
{
  //flip back the cards and empty the array
  holder_arr[0].showCover();
  holder_arr[1].showCover();
  holder_arr = [];
}
holder_arr.push(this);
...
..
```

7) For checking make a function and run it every time a card is clicked, and also when a timer ends, to flip back the cards.

```
function checkCards()
{
  if(holder_arr.length==2)
  {
     if(holder_arr[0].id==holder_arr[1].id)
     {
       //the cards match
       holder_arr[0].vanishAnim();
       holder_arr[1].vanishAnim();
       holder_arr=[];
     }
     else
     {
       holder_arr[0].showCover();
       holder_arr[1].showCover();
       holder_arr=[];
     }
  }
}
```

Obviously you will remove the cards from the actual card_arr too, but when to do that is up to you to figure out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally , I find the problem has more to do with the way you shuffle your cards as it makes it a bit more difficult to identify what card is what.

Let's say for instance that instead of shuffling your embed assets , you were first creating your cards , naming them after the image they add , then creating an Array ( or Vector ) of cards and shuffle that Array ( or Vector ), identifying the cards would be fairly easy since you'd only have to compare their name property.

```
   //PSEUDO CODE
   - create Array ( Vector ) of embed assets [PIC1, PIC2 , PIC3]
   - create cards and use Array ( Vector ) index to identify 
   each card with the name property
   - create a set of six cards
   - shuffle set
```